# How to upload the file using Junit Selenium?

Tags: java, selenium, web, junit

I tried to upload the file using JUNIT_Selenium.

```
WebElement fileInfo = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type='file']"));
fileInfo.sendKeys('my file root');
```

But, the popup window was not closed in this way :(

Cloud you please give me the answer to solve this problem?

(browser used : Chrome)

Answer (score 0):

I have used some special library Robot.

```
details.ClickChooseFile();

        StringSelection ss = new StringSelection("C:\\Your File");  
        waitmethod.Waitsec();
        Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard().setContents(ss, null);
        Robot robot = new Robot();

        waitmethod.Waitsec();
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_V);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_V);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);

        details.ClickSubmitEmpl();
```